# How to use events for abandoned carts?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, configuration, contactbuilder, e-commerce

So, I’m studying some configurations in Marketing Cloud and I’ve found that we can use the Events in Contact Builder to find contacts that abandoned their carts in some e-commerce. But I’m not finding any documentation that shows how to do it.

**Does anyone out there know how to use events for abandoned carts?**

Comment: Are you referencing to in abandoned  carts in Commerce Cloud? If yes, check out this link https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cross_cloud_marketing_commerce_kit_abandoned_cart.htm&type=5

Comment: Thanks for this comment! But I've already seen this documentation. I want to know if there is another way to connect marketing cloud to any e-commerce, not just that one that uses Commerce Cloud.